# A question about the relation between two independent random variables and their covariance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, covariance

We can easily know that if random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E[X])(E-E[Y])]$$
$$= E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$$
$$= E[X]E[Y]-E[X]E[Y]$$
$$= 0$$

So, if random variables X and Y are independent, we get $Cov(X,Y)=0$.

---

However, if $Cov(X,Y)=0$, can we get a conclusion that $X$ and $Y$ independent? My intuition tells me that it may not be ture. How can I prove my intuition? How can I construct a bunch of counter examples (both in discrete cases and in continuous cases)?

Comment: You need symmetry to get Cov(X, Y) = 0, but you need to avoid the normal distribution for which Cov(X, Y) = 0 implies independence. For one example, try a uniform distribution on a 'diamond' shaped region with vertices at (-1,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (0,-1).

Answer (score 0):

No, we can’t. Consider for example, as X~Norm(0,1) and Y be square of Standard Normal. In that case you also receive Cov(X,Y)=0, since E(X)=0 and E(Y)=0. However X and Y are highly dependent, because the knowledge of value of X tells us a lot of things about Y.

However, it is true in case of Multivariate Normal. For instance, take X and be as Norm(0,1) and check if it is true. Take as Multi. Normal(X+Y,X-Y) and compute the Cov(X+Y,X-Y)=Var(X)-Cov(X,Y)+Cov(X,Y)-Var(Y)=0, since Var(X)=Var(Y)=1